High school chemistry/biotechnologies - Topic: "EU and USA a comparison" - seeking advices on lesson plan / assessment
I am a teacher in an Italian high school, I teach English (second language).
This question is oriented to a classroom of around 20 students (19 years old), the level of English is quite low, probably around B1.
I need to develop a lesson plan (couple of lessons) with some content, on the multidisciplinary topic: European Union and United States of America, a comparison.
I would like this to concern the subject that I am teaching, English (language), but I would also like to include some concepts of their high school orientation: chemistry and biotech.
I am looking for some interesting topics that include these categories, that could maybe be interesting for a young adult crowd, of course not professionals, but probably interested in their studies.
I am also looking for a way to assess, more than their knowledge on the topic, having spent some time and "passion" to develop something, maybe even in groups.
I am bit lost and out of ideas, any idea, let me know :)

Both Fischer-Tropsch synthesis and Haber-Bosch synthesis are EU-borne. Both inventions were driven by a dare need. Why?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about chemistry per se.

Since you bring up biotech, an interesting topic is differences in legal standing of GMO. There are many similar questions of differences in permitted use of chemical compounds in EU vs USA.

(i) Names of the elements in English and in European languages and why their  symbols don't match their English names such as tungsten, which is W. Alternatively, make them find and write something on an element that was discovered in Italy (technetium, let them find using only English sources). Tc plays an important role in cancer treatment.
(ii) Finding modern elements discovered in the EU vs. USA after 1900s.
(iii) Writing something on famous Italian scientists or EU who came the USA and made their name (see Enrico Fermi as an example).
(iv) Ask them to how AI can integrate people across various languages in EU and the English speaking world in writing an essay. Use AI to translate a part scientific text from English to Italian and let them find mistakes/or do commentary in Italian or vice versa.

C&En published by the American Chemical Society equally cover e.g., business topics outside the U.S.A., or Lowe's In the pipeline on chemistryworld may be an other resource to teach more English around chemistry, than e.g. J. Chem. Educ. about chemistry.
